# Bootstrap glyhicon alignment in panel title

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set some glyphicons on a panel title but can't align left and right.
Tried to enclose with span or p but still doesn't work...
What is missing?

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
        <a class="text-left" href='#' style="margin-right: 10px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a>
        Page Title
        <a class="text-right" href='#'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: whats your actual desired output?

Comment: The refresh glyphicon and the title should be on the left and the remove-rign on the extreme right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the class `pull-right` and `pull-left` instead of `text-right` and `text-left` to anchor tags containing the glyphicon.

```
<h3 class="panel-title">
    <a class="pull-left" href='#' style="margin-right: 10px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a>
    Page Title
    <a class="pull-right" href='#'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></a>
</h3>
```